# ¿Como puedo saber si un número tiene decimales?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo un arreglo que obtengo de mysql donde el valor **cantidad_cosecha** es del tipo DECIMAL(8,3). Por ejemplo

```
$cosechas = [[
  'codigo_producto'=> 'A1',
  'cantidad_cosecha'=> '0.100',
],[
  'codigo_producto'=> 'A2',
  'cantidad_cosecha'=> '1.000',
],[
  'codigo_producto'=> 'A3',
  'cantidad_cosecha'=> '2.000',
]];
```

Al imprimirlos se ven así:

```
| Codigo | Cantidad |
| ------ | -------- |
| A1     | 0.100    |
| A2     | 1.000    |
| A3     | 2.000    |
```

Necesito que al imprimirlos los números que no tienen decimales se vean como enteros. Así:

```
| Codigo | Cantidad |
| ------ | -------- |
| A1     | 0.100    |
| A2     | 1        |
| A3     | 2        |
```

Este es mi código:

```
<table class="cosechas">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Fecha</th>
  <th>Codigo</th>
  <th>Producto</th>
  <th>Recolector</th>
  <th>Cantidad</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($cosechas as $dato) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', $dato['fecha_cosecha']) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dato['codigo_producto'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dato['nombre_producto'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dato['nombre_recolector'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dato['cantidad_cosecha'] ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
} ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que los números que no tienen decimales se vean como enteros?

Intente:

```
is_float($dato['cantidad_cosecha']) // Siempre da falso

(($dato['cantidad_cosecha']) % 1) == 0 // Me da error
// Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float-string "0.100" to int loses precision
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para saber si tiene decimales podemos hacer uso de:

- [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php)

  > Obtiene el valor entero de una variable
- [`floatval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.floatval.php)

  > Obtener el valor flotante de una variable

Si aplicamos `intval()` sobre el número vamos a obtener la parte entera del número.
Si aplicamos `floatval()` sobre el número vamos a obtener el número con decimales.
Si comparamos ambos resultados y:

- Si son iguales, es un número entero
- Si son distintos, es un número con decimales.

#### Solución:

Para obtener el resultado que necesitas podemos hacer lo siguiente:

- Si al comparar los números son iguales, imprimimos el número entero.
- Sino, imprimimos el número original.

**Ejemplo:**

```
echo intval($numero) == floatval($numero) ? intval($numero) : $numero;
```

Aplicado a tu caso podrías crear una función para obtener el numero formateado:

```php
function formatoDecimales($numero)
{
    return intval($numero) == floatval($numero) ? intval($numero) : $numero;
}
```

y luego utilizarla así:

```php
    <td><?php echo formatoDecimales($dato['cantidad_cosecha']); ?></td>
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://onlinephp.io/c/3188d)

Comment: ¡Gracias, me sirvió!

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto.

#### Usando `printf()` o `sprintf()`

Podrías usar `printf` con el marcador `g` (general format).

Por ejemplo:

```
foreach ($cosechas as $cosecha) {
    printf("%s %-10s %g \n",$cosecha['codigo_producto'],'',$cosecha['cantidad_cosecha']);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
A1            0.1 
A2            1 
A3            2
```

Para más detalles, consulta el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php).

Si te interesa concatenar los datos, para luego incorporarlos al `body` de la tabla, puedes usar `sprintf()`, hace lo mismo que `printf`, sólo que guarda los resultados en variables, mientras que `printf` los imprime directamente.

Por ejemplo, esto te crearía los `tr` y `td` de una tabla.

```
$rows="";
foreach ($cosechas as $cosecha) {
    $rows.=sprintf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%g</td>",$cosecha['codigo_producto'],$cosecha['cantidad_cosecha']);
}
#Incorporar $rows al body de la tabla
```

`$rows` tendrá esto:

```
<tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>0.1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
```

---

#### Añadiendo `+`

Esto obliga una conversión a float y remueve los zeros que haya en el punto decimal.

Por ejemplo:

```
foreach ($cosechas as $cosecha) {
    printf("%s %-10s %s \n",$cosecha['codigo_producto'],'',+$cosecha['cantidad_cosecha']);
}
```

**Salida:**

```
A1            0.1 
A2            1 
A3            2
```

Yo usaría `printf()` o `sprintf()`, porque además puedes clarificar un poco tu código, evitando mezclas de PHP / HTML, concatenando los resultados en una variable.

Comment: Hola A.Cedano, si hago `echo sprintf("%g", $dato['cantidad_cosecha'])` y es `0.100` el resultado tiene que ser con los 3 decimales. ¿Por qué evitar mezclar PHP y HTML? Así como lo hago es similar a utilizar un template, ¿está mal?

Comment: @Joaco si lo piensas bien, no tiene demasiado sentido. O sea, `0.1` es lo mismo que `0.100` o que `0.10000000000000`, en ambos casos la forma estándar es eliminar todos los `0` inútiles.

Comment: @Joaco si la idea es quitar los decimales, solamente cuando sean `0` puedes recurrir por ejemplo a un `explode()`, sobrecargando el código para algo que no tiene sentido realmente, por lo dicho en mi anterior comentario.

Comment: Es verdad, pero es un requerimiento. Si de mi dependiera los dejaría a todos con los tres decimales, jajaja

Comment: @Joaco creo que en ese caso la solución de Marcos será la más confiable.